# Displaying new line in shell variable

Tags: unix, newline

While executing the below script:

```
export var1="string('\n')"

echo $var1
```

I get the output as `string(n)`. But I expect to see the output as : `"string('\n')"`.

Is there any way to get that?

**Note:** I need the output to be displayed in `string('\n')` (`\n` in single quotes) to use that variable in `m_wc abinitio` command.

**Update:** Thanks for responding quickly, but the variable text goes to next line when '\n' occurs. output below:

```
export var='string('\''\n'\'')'
export var1="string('\\n')"
echo "$var1"
string('
')
>echo $var
string('
')
```

Is there any way to escape the '\n' entirely?

Update : printf '%s\n' "$var1" seems to be working fine, but how can i put this value to a variable and use it anywhere in the script ?

I tried to put like below : but does not work:

export var1="string('\n')"

export var2="printf '%s\n' "$var1""

export BYT_CNT=`m_wc -no-commas -string $var2 /prod/users/edw/gvx770/list.dat|awk '{print $1}'`

echo $var2

echo $var2
printf '%s
' string('
')

Comment: Don't use `echo`; use `printf '%s\n' "$var1"`.  You don't know what different versions of `echo` are going to do; different shells handle backslash escapes in arguments differently.  `printf` is consistent and standardized by POSIX — and does what you want.  Note the single quotes around the format string `'%s\n'` and the double quotes around `"$var1"`; both are a good idea, for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is probably:

```
export var1="string('\\n')"
echo "$var1"
```

Comment: ...also checkout this brief article on **[escape sequences in UNIX shell](http://steve-parker.org/sh/escape.shtml)**.

Comment: Hi William, Thanks for responding but it variable text goes to next line when '\n' occurs. output below:
export var1="string('\\n')"
>echo "$var1"
string('
')

Is there any way to escape \n ?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
export var='string('\''\n'\'')'
```

What you need to know is:

1. You can include anything between single-quotes except for an apostrophe; and
2. You can quote an apostrophe by preceding it with a backslash, outside of any single- or double-quoting.

With those two rules, you can quote anything in shell.

Alternatively, you can use double-quotes, but the rules for using it effectively are more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got the solution to fix this issue. Here is the code:

export dir="string('\n')"

export j=$(printf "%s\n" $dir)

export BYT_CNT=`m_wc -no-commas -string "$j" /temp/users/list.dat | awk '{print $1}'`

echo  $BYT_CNT

Thanks guys for all your help.